# "PKIX path building failed" exception when distributed CAS applications on separate Tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat, ssl, cas

Recently, I started working on configuring Spring web applications to use with Jasig CAS. Everything is ok when I run CAS client and CAS server in a server created inside Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite) that already configured to use SSL. I was able to run, authenticate, log out... However, when I create a Tomcat instance with the same server.xml as the server in STS and let the applications run on it, this exception occurred after entering username, password to CAS server login form and the server redirect to client login page with generated ticket:

```
HTTP Status 500 - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I used the same keystore and truststore file as in STS Tomcat server and the certificate already imported into file jre/lib/security/cacerts.

When I tried to run CAS client in Eclipse Tomcat server together with CAS server in stand-alone Tomcat server, it was ok. But it did not work vice versa.

Is there any difference between STS Tomcat instance and stand alone Tomcat instance? Both refer to the same CATALINA_BASE.

I use Tomcat 7.0.67, CAS 3.6.0, Spring Security 3.1.4.

Comment: Q: Are you absolutely positively sure you imported the certificate into the right JRE's keystore?  And yes, STS basically "is Tomcat".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Only one JRE on my system, I also check with Portecle and see it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. I installed both JRE and JDK. Tomcat in Eclipse uses JRE but stand-alone Tomcat uses JRE inside JDK. I import certificate into this JRE and it works. Thank paulsm4 for the suggestion.